# laravel filesystem using S3 - custom metadata

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

Amazon S3 allows you to attach custom metadata to objects however I have been unable to figure out how to access this data using the laravel filesystem. Searching shows little information about this. Does anyone know how to access that data?

EDIT: I found a method in Storage to display the metadata HOWEVER it does not seem to include the custom meta key and string I added to the image via the S3 control panel.

```
return Storage::getMetaData($path);
```

results:

```
{ 
  "path":"toolkit\/social-media\/facebook\/cover-image\/SG-Chivalry-Facebook-Cover-Co-Branded.jpg",
  "dirname":"toolkit\/social-media\/facebook\/cover-image","basename":"SG-Chivalry-Facebook-Cover-Co-Branded.jpg",
  "extension":"jpg",
  "filename":"SG-Chivalry-Facebook-Cover-Co-Branded",
  "timestamp":1460581502,
  "size":"113476",
  "mimetype":"image\/jpeg",
  "type":"file"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found a solution using php get_headers function:

```
return get_headers("file.jpg");
```

Returns all the metadata including custom metadata fields from S3